# How do I scope method options?

Tags: ruby

I have an option parsing gem that provides a DSL for creating commands. In practice, it often ends up looking like this:

```
option :ints,    Integer, arity: [1, -1], on_multiple: :append
option :floats,  Float,   arity: [1, -1], on_multiple: :append
option :complex, Complex, arity: [1, -1], on_multiple: :append
```

These are class methods. Not very DRY, as you can see. It would be better to write something like this:

```
scope arity: [1, -1], on_multiple: :append do
  option :ints,    Integer
  option :floats,  Float
  option :complex, Complex
end
```

To have the options hash given to `scope` transparently merged with the one given to `option`. That's where I'm stuck. I'm not sure where to store the common options so that I can merge them later.

Any ideas?

---

`option` forwards everything to `Option#new`:

```
def option(*args, &block)
  # self is a class that represents a command
  self.options << Option.new(*args, &block)
end
```

As requested, here's the code, with usage of support gems removed:

```
def initialize(key, *args, &block)
  # Retrieve the options hash from the argument array.
  options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop : {}

  # The rest of the implementation...
  type = args.find { |arg| arg.is_a? Module }

  strings = args.flatten.select do |arg|
    arg.is_a? String
  end.group_by do |arg|
    arg =~ Parser::Regexp::SWITCH ? :switches : :description
  end

  self.key = key
  self.names = strings.fetch(:switches) { [ Option.name_from(key) ] }
  self.description = options.fetch :description, strings.fetch(:description, []).first
  self.on_multiple = options.fetch :on_multiple, :replace
  self.arity = options.fetch :arity, nil
  self.default = options.fetch :default, nil
  self.required = options.fetch :required, false
  self.type = type || String
  self.handler = block
end
```

[Original on GitHub](https://github.com/matheusmoreira/acclaim/blob/master/lib/acclaim/option.rb#L72).

Comment: What does your `option` function look like now?

Comment: @sarnold, it effectively takes `key, *args, &block` as arguments. The options hash is either the last element of `args` or an empty hash. The implementation basically processes `args` to initialize an `Option` object. Should I post the code?

Comment: I think you should post the code, it's often far easier for others to make concrete suggestions if they've got a sketch of the currently working code to work with.

Comment: Excellent; good job cutting it down, too! That's a skill.

Comment: Why you can't just create another method or lamda function with already set arity and other paramaters?

Comment: @megas, I designed the DSL for fine-grained control over the number of parameters. I could create helpers for the common usage, but what about the unusual cases? In those cases, it would be nice to allow people to override the defaults for a certain group of options in a DRY manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Object#with_options](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options) from Rails, and swipe that for your own use.